# Spark SQL conditionally select column based on column data type

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column which sometimes is a string, other times a string array with a single element. Unfortunately I don't have a means to change this behavior so it always have one data type.

When the column is an array, I need to select its first element, when it contains a string, I need to select another column.

When I do:

```
SELECT IFNULL(`myColumn`[0],`myOtherColumn`) FROM myTable
```

If myColumn is a string it throws:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from
> myColumn#691: need struct type but got string

I checked out [java_method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#java_method), but afaik it only works with static methods from java libraries, so I can't use [isArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray--) or some other instance method.

Is there a way to conditionally select columns based on column data type?

Comment: A column can only have one single data type. Could you show the schema of the table?

Comment: Yes but, column is dynamically generated by a library code (spark-solr), which gives it an appropriate type depending on other things. So when I run the sql with different data the column is sometimes an array, sometimes a string.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have multiple tables with different column types, or do you have one single table with a column having multiple types? The latter doesn't sound possible to me. Anyway, could you do `describe table myTable`?

Comment: spark-solr library is used to load data from Solr into Spark. User specifies some parameters, which turns into a Solr query, whose result is loaded into myTable by spark-solr. myColumn field is an array in some Solr collections, string in others, so depending on what the user specified, each resulting myTable have different schemas, but my SQL needs to work in both conditions. I hope I could clarify. Yes I have 2 different tables with different column types, but can only have 1 sql which should work for both.

Comment: Developing software for this type of weird situation  means --> go back to source and clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out a way to put a column type check into a case when, but here is a hack which could work:

```
select
    case when (substring(cast(myColumn as string), 1, 1) = '[') and 
              (substring(cast(myColumn as string), -1, 1) = ']')
         then split(trim(both '[]' from cast(myColumn as string)), ',')[0]
         else myOtherColumn
         end
from myTable;
```

Of course this could fail in case the string happens to begin with `[` or end with `]`. If you could use pyspark/scala you can do it in a more reliable way by checking the column types.